# Split squats over normal squats

Tags: exercise, muscle, training, muscle-mass, muscle-gain

Today I tried split squats just for curiosity, did a superset of 5 sets with barbell and 5 with dumbbells and then a dropset with dumbbells. 
I already did supersets and drops with normal squats but I've always only felt it in my quadriceps and a little bit in my glutes.

But with splits I have felt my hamstrings and quadriceps both burning from one exercise and I also noticed an absurdly incredible burn in my gluteus medius, actually this was the first time in my life noticing anything in the gluteus medius. 
Are split squats superior to normal squats since they seem to work more muscles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Research suggests](https://digitalcommons.wku.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://duckduckgo.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1607&context=ijes) that rear-leg elevated split squats ("Bulgarian split squats") activate the biceps femoris on the eccentric part of the movement more than conventional squats. Additionally, it is an unilateral movement and can help you correct muscular imbalances between legs.

Now is it the superior exercise? This depends entirely on your personal goals. Do you want to focus more on training your hamstrings, your balance or just want to try something new? Go for it! Are you planning to go to a powerlifting/weightlifting meet? Stick to normal back squats!

However, the amount of soreness is not a good indicator of the effectiveness of an exercise - Any kind of new exercise will make you sore. The higher the eccentric load in a movement, the more likely it is to cause soreness, as well (hence you often see olympic lifters just dropping their bars after the concentric movement, instead of bringing it back to the ground in a controlled fashion).

Comment: I'm not a competitor.

Comment: I see it as more bang for my buck in this case.

Comment: it seems like an absolute valid replacement exercise. If you can hold your balance at high loads - why not?

Comment: Speaking about the eccentric movement,in case of DL training,do we lose any gains if we drop it like the powerlifters do?

Comment: What powerlifter drops the deadlift? If you don't stick with the bar until it's dead on the floor again, it counts as a failed attempt.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean dropping the bar,but not really controlling all the way down, slowly.

Comment: Ah, I see. I know no one that does this, at least not with heavy sets. The DL as it is is already a b*tch to recover from, focusing on the eccentric part would leave you with even more soreness, also it sounds like a great way to injure your knees and your discs. Slow eccentric movement on assistance style DL variants, like stiff-legged or romanian, done in the higher rep ranges are a common sight on the other hand.

Comment: Quote from Louie Simmons on that matter: “Slow eccentrics have no place in powerlifting. To build larger muscles, yes. If you want to become very sore, yes. What does it matter if you can lower 60% more than you can raise? If I recall correctly, you must raise the bar from the floor.”

Comment: Yeah,and to top that,I have heard some powerlifters that there's not much strength gains to lose in case we don't really slow it all the way down in a DL in case we are strength training.